# Android: Erro no getContext() ao utilizar SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-context

Estou a usar `SharedPreferences` com `Retrofit2` e `notificações`. Cada vez que a Notificação é executada obtenho a excepção "`'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference`".

Estou a chamar o `Retrofit` para executar a notificação de uma classe que `extend` de `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void createNotification(Context context, String exemplo) {

        ExtendedActivity ext = new ExtendedActivity();
        ext.start(exemplo);
(...)
```

Classe ExtendedActivity

```
public class ExtendedActivity extends BaseActivity implements Callback<Channel>{

String descript="descript";

@Override
    public void start(String texto) {
    (...)
}

@Override
    public void onResponse(Call<Channel> call, Response<Channel> response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        Channel rss = response.body();

        saveData(descript, rss.getItemDescription()); <--------- ERRO
     }
 }

    public void saveData(String key, String time){
        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getContext()); <-----ERRO
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        if (preferences.contains(key)) {
            editor.remove(key);
        }

    editor.putString(key, time);
    editor.commit();
}
```

O problema esta no contexto do metodo `saveData`. Já tentei utilizar o contexto de outras actividades e continua sempre a dar-me erro. Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: Em vez de `this.getContext()` use `this`.

Comment: Além que esse método nem existe na classe Activity, a não ser que tenha sido declarado na BaseActivity.

Comment: @ramaral, alterei para this, coloquei um Log antes e não é nulo, mas continuo a obter a excepção java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference no saveData()

Comment: Você não pode fazer isto `ExtendedActivity ext = new ExtendedActivity();`

Comment: @ramaral obrigada